# Save .txt file in project directory as Do Not Copy in runtime

Tags: c#, .net

I have to save .txt files in runtime in the Project Root Directory in the directory UpdateScripts but as Do Not Copy, so that it cannot be deleted from other users.

With `File.WriteAllText()` and getting the path of the BaseDirectory from `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory()`, you can save it in the Project directory, but it will logically be visible as a file in the final build.

How can I achieve it? Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can get your created file like this.

```
FileInfo myFile= new FileInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\myFile.txt");
```

Later, change the file hidden attribute like this.

```
myFile.Attributes |= FileAttributes.Hidden;
```